# Marionette Layout: trigger event on child view

Tags: events, backbone.js, marionette

I have a layout view, with an itemView inside it. I have an event in my item view that triggers a save function. Inside that save function I would like to trigger another event that the layout captures.

So in the code below, in the onClickSave modelSaveSuccess I'd like to trigger a function in the parent layout, I have tried this.methodInParent() but it doesnt work

childView

```
define(["marionette", "underscore", "text!app/templates/client/form.html", "app/models/client"], function(Marionette, _, Template, Model) {
  "use strict"
  return Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    events: {
      "submit #saveClient": "onClickSave"
    },
    onClickSave: function(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault()
      return this.model.save({}, {
        success: function() {
          console.log('success - trigger ')
        },
        error: function(request, error) {
          console.log(error.responseText)
        }
      })
    }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good way to do it without introducing heavy coupling is to use Marionette's [event aggregator](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.application.md#appvent-event-aggregator) as in the linked exemple if you use Backbone.Marionette.application.

```
// in your view
...
success: function() {
    app.vent.trigger('myview:modelsaved');
}
...

// in your layout initialize()
...
app.vent.on('myview:modelsaved', function(){
   console.log('model saved in itemView');
});
...
```

If you don't use Backbone.Marionette.Application you can always create your own Backbone.Wreqr.EventAggregator.

Comment: Note: Marionette now has 'childEvents' in LayoutView